# asp.net dropdownlist not updating selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, postback, html-select

I have a page with a gridview on it and a dropdown list which controls how many items per page the gridview will display.

The pageSize value of the gridview is controlled by this dropdown list and it gets saved to a cookie.
When the user loads the site the cookie is read so that it remembers what page size the user picked.

I have one problem and that is, if I pick another value on the dropdown list it does not update either cookie or dropdown list. It reverts back to the saved value.

This is the dropdown list created in the gridview pager template:

```
<PagerTemplate>
             <asp:Table ID="Table3" runat="server" Width="100%">
                 <asp:TableRow>
                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Left">
                         <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                     <asp:TableCell HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="10%">
                         Page Size
                            <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlPageSize" AutoPostBack="true"
                                 OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged" OnLoad="ddlPageSize_Load">
                                <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>100</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                     </asp:TableCell>
                 </asp:TableRow>
             </asp:Table>
        </PagerTemplate>
```

and this is where I try to load the value of the dropdown list from cookie:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pageSize = "10";
            //Try and load the PageSize cookie from the user's machine and default to 10 records if none is found.
            if (Request.Cookies["PageSize"] != null)
            {                
                if (Request.Cookies["PageSize"]["Value"] != null)
                {
                    pageSize = Request.Cookies["PageSize"]["Value"];
                    int _pageSize;
                    int.TryParse(pageSize, out _pageSize);
                    gvRecordsList.PageSize = _pageSize;
                    DropDownList ddlPageSize = (gvRecordsList.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("ddlPageSize") as DropDownList;
                    ddlPageSize.SelectedIndex = ddlPageSize.Items.IndexOf(new ListItem(pageSize));
                }
            }
            else
                gvRecordsList.PageSize = 10;


            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                ApplyPaging();               
            }
            else
            {
                gvRecordsList.DataSourceID = "RecordsListSqlDataSource";
                gvRecordsList.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

The dropdown list index changed code:

```
protected void ddlPageSize_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DropDownList ddlPageSize = (gvRecordsList.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("ddlPageSize") as DropDownList;
            gvRecordsList.PageSize = int.Parse(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue);
            Response.Cookies["PageSize"]["Value"] = ddlPageSize.SelectedValue;
            Response.Cookies["PageSize"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
        }
```

When I step through the code of the SelectedIndexChanged method, I can see that ddlPageSize.SelectedValue always contains the value from the cookie, 50, even though I select another value.

I guess the question is, where do I set the index of the dropdown list?

```
DropDownList ddlPageSize = (gvRecordsList.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("ddlPageSize") as DropDownList;
                        ddlPageSize.SelectedIndex = ddlPageSize.Items.IndexOf(new ListItem(pageSize));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Page_Load` event executes before the `DropDownList` `SelectedIndexChanged` event. And you are loading the cookie's value to the `DropDownList` on the `PageLoad` event.

I suggest you to try loading the cookie afterwards, on the `OnPreRender` event for example.

Or add a condition to your `Page_Load` logic, verifying if the PostBack is caused by the `DropDownList`:

```
DropDownList ddlPageSize = (gvRecordsList.BottomPagerRow).FindControl("ddlPageSize") as DropDownList;      
bool isDDLPostingBack = Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == ddlPageSize.UniqueID;

if (Request.Cookies["PageSize"]["Value"] != null && !isDDLPostingBack)
{
...
}
```

Comment: If I place the cookie reading in Page_PreRenderComplete I can almost get it to work except that I must change the dropdown list twice in order for the value to change. It seems that when it goes to read the cookie it finds two copies of PageSize and I can also see that inside the Cookies folder a new one is created each time. That can't be right.